# If I refund an app purchase, will that person's review be removed?

Tags: android, google-play

A person left a negative review (1 star) on my app with a comment stating that I didn't give him a refund.

This is really unfair since I don't have many reviews yet, so the average really goes down. Plus, the app works fine, he is just complaining that I didn't give him a refund (which I'm willing to do, I just wasn't able to do it before the review was posted).

If I issue a refund, will that user's comment and review be removed? (since he no longer will have the app installed)